# Take flex item out of flow - IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a container with `display:flex;` Within that container I will sometimes have 2 items or sometimes I will have 3 items. I am using `justify-content:space-between;` and I want the 2 items to be spaced this way. When there's a 3rd item, I still want those original 2 items to be `space-between` and then I want the 3rd item to be out of the flex flow. To accomplish this I am using `position:absolute;` on the 3rd item. In Chrome/Firefox/Safari this works fine, but in IE, the absolutely positioned item is taking on the `space-between` so the positioning of the 2nd element element is off(it is placed directly in the middle of the container). How can I resolve this? I am open to alternate solutions, but I cannot change the structure of the HTML so it would have to be a CSS-based solution.

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  margin:30px auto;
  position:relative;
}
  .flex.abs {
    padding-left:40px;
  }
    .flex.abs div:first-child {
      position:absolute;
      left:-30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex abs">
  <div>Absolute</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks in Chrome(desired):
[image]

And here's how it looks in IE:
[image]

Comment: could post a picture of how you need it to look like?

Comment: It looks as expected in Chrome(only the non absolutely positioned elements are utilizing `space-between`) I've added a screenshot from Chrome to show desired output

Comment: But in chrome is still pushing the Item 1 a little to the right

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet That's due to the `padding-left:40px;` which is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with only `margin` without the need of `position:absolute`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.flex div:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.flex div:last-child {
   margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div>Absolute</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you for the alternate solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you make Item 1 a flex container you won't need position absolute,

Here's an idea

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-start {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-start">
    <div>Absolute</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution as well, but unfortunately I cannot alter the HTML structure.